# Compute the maximum value of $a + 2b + 3c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2$. Compute the maximum value of $a + 2b + 3c$.

I have been solving similar problems using Cauchy-Schwarz. However, I do not know how to start this problem. Do I write $a^2=2-b^2-c^2$ or $a^2+b^2=2-c^2$ and work from there, or do I start using something else.

Comment: $a+2b+3c=(1,2,3)\cdot(a,b,c)\leq (1^2+2^2+3^2)^{1/2}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{14}\sqrt{2}$. The equality holds when $(a,b,c)$ and $(1,2,3)$ are colinear. This is, for $(a,b,c)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{14}}(1,2,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+b^2+c^2=2$ is a sphere of radius $\sqrt 2$ around the origin.  The values of $a+2b+3c$ are constant on planes perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$.  Find the point in the first octant where $a+2b+3c=k$ is tangent to the sphere and you are there.